# read text from url line by line in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, file

I am trying to read data from url which is text file line by line, but i'm getting whole data instead of line by line.
It's working fine for large data but it's not working for small data.

```
url = request.GET.get('url')

data = []
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as f:
    data = [list(map(int, line.split('\n'))) for line in f]
```

The above code gives me right answer for files having large row size but it's not working for small data.

For example:(the text file contains)

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

and I need a list which looks something like this:

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: you can convert your 2Diemensional array into a 1Dimensional array and see if it works.

Comment: can anyone send the query for the above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `readlines()` method

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('url')

data = response.readlines()
```

Comment: This is not working for me, Is there any way to do it in the way i'm doing